# Understanding template code bloat

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading Scott Meyers C++ and came across with the concept of so-called *code bloat*. He provided an example of how to reduce it with inheritance:

```
template <typename T>
class SquareMatrixBase{
protected:
    void invert(std::size_t matrixSize);    // <------------ HERE
}

template <typename T, std::size_t n>
class SquareMatrix : private SquareMatrixBase<T>{
private:
    using SquareMatrix<T>::invert;
public:
    void invert(){ invert(n) }
}
```

Now, in the summary of the item he stated that

> Templates generate multiple classes and multiple functions, so any
>   template code not dependent on a template parameter causes bloat.

So, in the example we have `SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(std::size_t)` which is not dependent on the template parameter. So, it causes code bloat. Isn't that the thing we tried to eliminate? What did I miss?

Comment: Where's the inheritance? You probably meant `class SquareMatrix : private SquareMatrixBase<T>` and later `using SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, in the example we have `SquareMatrixBase<T>::invert(std::size_t)` which is not dependent on the template parameter. So, it causes code bloat. Isn't that the thing we tried to eliminate?  What did I miss?

No.  You missed that the operations `invert` performs on the matrix will be dependent on `T`, so it's appropriate to have one instantiation of `invert` for each `T`.

It is *not* desirable to have one instantiation for every combination of type `T` and matrix size `n`, which is why the derived `SquareMatrix` class - that is templated on both those parameters - defers to the base class' implementation.  It's effectively just injecting the matrix size constant as a runtime value.

Answer (score 2):

As the `SquareMatrix` template is parameterized on two things `T` and `n`, then even though you might have the same type `T`, if you were to have a different `n` and `invert` was a member function of `SquareMatrix`, it results in multiple versions of the function (a number depending on how many `SquareMatrix`'s of the same `T` but different sizes we instantiate).

Scott is demonstrating how we can avoid the potential bloat caused by these multiple copies, by simply inheriting from a type that is only parameterized on `T` and so can share an implementation of `invert` regardless of the value of `n`.

He passes the size value at runtime to the base class function and so all the same information is available to that function.